# What does bounded mean in this context?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a bounded, equicontinuous set of functions in $C^{0}[a,b]$.  What
does the term bounded mean in this context?  Does it mean there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$
such that $\|f\| = \sup{f([a,b])} \leq M$ for all $f \in \mathcal{E}$?

Comment: Yes. In normed spaces, a subset $S$ is - by definition - bounded if and only if it is contained in some ball $B_r(0) = \{ x : \lVert x\rVert < r\}$.

Comment: In metric spaces a set $A$ is bounded if exists some $r>0$ such that $d(x,y)<r$ for all $x,y\in A$. Then for normed spaces this is equivalent to say that exists some $r>0$ such that $\|x-y\|<r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: a subset $\mathcal{E}$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is bounded if it is contained in a ball of radius $R$ for some $R$. In this context $X = C^0[a,b]$ and $d(f,g) = \sup|f - g|$.